# Which DIR is the MySQL base directory after yum installed mysql

Tags: mysql

Seems that I cannot locate mysql DIR only bunch of binary files under `/usr/bin`

I used `yum` to install

```
mysql
mysql-server
mysql-devel
```

and tried to install `mysql` and I used `/init.d/mysqld` to have started it.

But when I want to compile PHP , the option `--with-mysql` need the base DIR of mysql ...where should I use?  `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should run this command

```
mysqladmin -uroot variables | grep datadir | sed 's/|/ /g' | awk '{print $2}'
```

to find the default data directory.

If you cannot login to mysql just yet, you can still run this

```
which mysqld
which mysqld_safe
```

to locate the binaries.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `/usr/local/mysql/bin`?

Comment: no mysql directory under /usr/local

Comment: Did you look in /usr/bin for the binaries?

Comment: Yes, that's the only place that I thought MySQL yum install had been installed files to..

Comment: Depending upon the distro and/or package it usually puts things in either /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Glad you got it sorted!